# ansible-galaxy failing for init install - Failed to get data from the API server - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: ansible-2.x, ansible-galaxy, telegraf, wavefront-telegraf

ansible: **ansible-galaxy 2.2.0.0**

python: **Python 2.7.10**

I tried ansible-galaxy command to create a new role structure (`init` command) but it failed with the following message. So, I looked online and  tried `--offline` option and structure creation part worked.

So far, I have my Github repo: https://github.com/asangal/wavefront-ansible

Role is also visible in Ansible Galaxy under `Browse Roles`.

https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles?page=1&page_size=10&autocomplete=wavefront or

https://galaxy.ansible.com/asangal/wavefront-ansible/

As per the instructions, I'm trying to run the install step by running 
but it failed again with the same error message as shown below.

```
$ ansible-galaxy install asangal.wavefront-ansible
 [WARNING]: - asangal.wavefront-ansible was NOT installed successfully: Failed to get data from the API server (https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/): a bytes-like object is
required, not 'str'

ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

OR (used `--ignore-errors` and `-p <role_path>` options but it didn't help)

```
$ ansible-galaxy install asangal.wavefront-ansible --ignore-errors -p ~/aks/dummy
 [WARNING]: - asangal.wavefront-ansible was NOT installed successfully: Failed to get data from the API server (https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/): a bytes-like object is
required, not 'str'

[arun@vagrant ~/aks/dummy] $ ls -l
[arun@vagrant ~/aks/dummy] $
```

`curl -v https://galaxy.ansible.com/asangal/wavefront-ansible/` seems to work fine.

Why am I getting this error: `Failed to get data from the API server (https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/): a bytes-like object is
    required, not 'str'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your role downloads fine for me with Python 2.7.13.

The `bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` is Python3 related, i suspect you should be ok if you use Python 2.x.

Comment: I'm python `Python 2.7.10`, let me try with 2.7.13. It's true that my `$ which ansible-galaxy
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/ansible-galaxy` ansible/ansible-* sits in the above `bin` path. That actually worked when my ansible was not coming from the above path. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Zlemini. So to clarify:

My ansible is actually was coming from Python 3.5 path. Even though default python was 2.7.10.

```
[arun@host ~/aks/dummy] $ python --version
Python 2.7.10
[arun@host ~/aks/dummy] $ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
[arun@host ~/aks/dummy] $ 

[arun@host ~/aks/dummy] $ which ansible-galaxy
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/ansible-galaxy
[arun@host ~/aks/dummy] $ 

[arun@host ~/aks/dummy] $ which ansible
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/ansible
```

Running the same `install` command it from my other vagrant machine where, `ansible` was actually coming from `/usr/bin/ansible`, the command worked as expected.

```
$ ansible-galaxy install asangal.wavefront-ansible -p ~/aks/dummy
- downloading role 'wavefront-ansible', owned by asangal
- downloading role from https://github.com/asangal/wavefront-ansible/archive/master.tar.gz
- extracting asangal.wavefront-ansible to /home/vagrant/dummy/asangal.wavefront-ansible
- asangal.wavefront-ansible was installed successfully
[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/dummy] $ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 9 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jan 24 23:16 asangal.wavefront-ansible
```